# How to force a linker error on a specific section

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, sections

I use GCC and GNU Binutils on Linux, to compile and link code for i386 Linux. I'd like to disallow the section named `.custom`, so I'd like the following to fail with a compile error or a link error:

```
__attribute__((section(".custom"))) int foo() { return 42; }
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

, but this one should succeed as usual:

```
__attribute__((section(".other" ))) int foo() { return 42; }
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

The code doing `__attribute__((section(".custom")))` is not under my control (so I can't simply replace it with an `#error` in the `.c` file), but the `gcc` and `ld` command-line flags (and the build process) are under my control.

Is there a command-line flag for `gcc` or `ld` or some other trick which can force the error? I couldn't find anything relevant in the man pages.

My fallback solution is to parse the generated executable (e.g. using `objdump -x`), and fail with an error message if the `.custom` section has made it to the final executable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a linker script to discard all symbols in the `.custom` section:

```
SECTIONS
{
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.custom) }
}
```

If you really wanted to punish your users with an error, rather than simply discarding the symbols, I suppose you could instead have the linker script `ASSERT` that the size of the `.custom` section was 0. I think you'd have to force the section to be generated for that to work, though.. otherwise it'd give you an error that the section didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I indeed need an error so that the user gets to know that the functionality he is asking for doesn't exist in this build.